# Swap Area partition

Tags: swap

I created a swap area with gparted successfully.How can know if swap area is created? I created the swap area after the Ubuntu installation. When i write `swapon -s` command to terminal there appears one table but it is empty. The "filename option", "size option" are all empty. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The `swapon -s` command is what you want to use to see your swap partition that are active.

To know whether you have a swap partition on disk, use parted.

Now what you probably want is to use the swap partition... It should appear in your file `/etc/fstab` as something that looks like this:

```
# swap was on /dev/md7 during installation
UUID=4be93050-8c7c-4975-8729-7af473de4847 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Once you edited the /etc/fstab, run the swapon command like this to activate your swap:

```
swapon -a
```

If you know the UUID of your partition, it is easy to add. Assuming you created that one additional partition, you can find the list here:

```
ls /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

and you should be able to deduce what UUID it is (i.e. the one that's not used anywhere else.)

Comment: does Creating swap area  mean that ubuntu is using swap area?And I gave swap area 5 GiB is it much or less?

Comment: When I controlled disk utility i can see my swap area there.When ı write  sudo blkid | grep swap this command ı can see like this:       UUID=4be93050-8c7c-4975-8729-7af473de4847 Type="Swap"

Comment: Yes, actually I forgot something, once created in the /etc/fstab, you want to start it without rebooting, you need to do a `swapon -a`